# Excel VBA FTP connection failing following January 2016 Microsoft Office 2010 update

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, ftp, ms-office

I have a file I use to pass a .txt file of data into a folder on my ftp. The macro that runs takes the data in the active sheet, formats it correctly, creates a new file and then pushes that file to the ftp. As of Friday this macro is no longer running correctly: the new file is created, but not pushed successfully to the ftp. I had various security updates and Microsoft Office updates installed automatically on Friday, which I think has caused the issue. Does anyone know a workaround and what in the update may have caused this to fail?

FTP code as follows (I have removed formatting/file creation code):

```
'Open the Internet object
 Private Declare Function InternetOpen _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetOpenA" _
       (ByVal sAgent As String, _
        ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
        ByVal sProxyName As String, _
        ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

'Connect to the network
 Private Declare Function InternetConnect _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetConnectA" _
       (ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
        ByVal sServerName As String, _
        ByVal nServerPort As Integer, _
        ByVal sUsername As String, _
        ByVal sPassword As String, _
        ByVal lService As Long, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long, _
        ByVal lContext As Long) As Long

'Send a file using FTP
 Private Declare Function FtpPutFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpPutFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszLocalFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean

'Close the Internet object
 Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     (ByVal hInet As Long) As Integer

RetVal = False
      INet = InternetOpen("MyFTP Control", 1&, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0&)
        If INet > 0 Then
          INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, ServerName, 0&, UserName, Password, 1&, 0&, 0&)
            If INetConn > 0 Then
              Success = FtpPutFile(INetConn, localFile, hostFile, BINARY_TRANSFER, 0&)
              RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INetConn)
            End If
         RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INet)
        End If

      If Success <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Upload process completed")
      Else
        MsgBox "FTP File Error!"
      End If
```

Comment: Does rolling your system back to pre-update with system restore 'fix' the issue?

Comment: Check 'Trusted Folders' or 'Trusted Locations' under options. It probably isn't that, but you start by looking in the easy places.

Comment: If you're in a corporate environment, it's possible that your Office update isn't the only thing that changed over the weekend: test your ftp folder manually in Explorer, it's likely that something's changed there, too - passwords, Active Directory mediated access, replacement with an sftp service. If your problem is that the ftp server is blocking transfers originating in VBScript (and VBA with it) then your manual test won't tell you very much: but the first step is validating that the folder still works

Comment: Can you connect to the server via the FTP command line tool? Where does the code fail? Call GetLastError immediately after the failing call for an error code (and InternetGetLastResponseInfo for InternetConnect)

Comment: The InternetConnect runs no problem - it looks like it's the FtpPutFile specifically that doesn't run successfully.